# Get system's first day of the week in Flutter

Tags: flutter, datetime

Is there a way of getting the first day of the week from device info or locale in Flutter? I use some libraries for which it has to be manually set, so I need to get it somehow. Or maybe, at least, these is even a library you might know which returns first day of the week by locale code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `subtract` method to get first day of the week according to user's device locate

```
DateTime today = DateTime.now();             
_firstDayOfTheweek = today.subtract(new Duration(days: today.weekday));
```

Or you can do that with material localization and get it from `context`

```
MaterialLocalizations.of(context).firstDayOfWeekIndex;
```